# Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I new there are lots of answer as well as accepted answers related to this question but none of them solve my problem. Still I am getting this error.

Procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllProducts()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM products;
END //

CREATE PROCEDURE getAllCategories()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM category;
END //
```

Connection & calling:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $link) or die(mysql_error());

$allProducts = mysql_query("CALL getAllProducts");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($allProducts)) { }

$allCategory = mysql_query("CALL getAllCategories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($allCategory)) { }
```

I've even called `mysql_free_result($allProducts)` before executing the next query. But nothing happens.

`mysql_get_client_info()` return `mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $`

I found that the problem only arises if I run two queries.

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` after _every_ call.

Answer (score 0):

As the MySQL-Documentation for ['Commands out of sync'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) points out:

> [...] It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
>   without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

The Documentation for [mysql_use_result()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-use-result.html) says e.g.:

> After invoking mysql_query() or mysql_real_query(), you **must** call
>   mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() for every statement that
>   successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN,
>   CHECK TABLE, and so forth). You **must** **also** call mysql_free_result()
>   after you are done with the result set.

Basically you need to tell your client what it should do with the result.

Comment: I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_store_result() `

Comment: Have you considered using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? Since the mysql module of php is [deprecated sice PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) you should not use it. Also mysql-modules have been removed from PHP 7.0.0. If you run PHP 7+ it may be that this causes a problem.

Comment: This is a legacy project written in PHP 5.3.0 and `mysql` not `mysqli`. Now it is not possible to convert it to `mysqli`. Can you please help me from here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually this error occurs because there are still results pending from the query. There are `mysqli_store_result` and `mysqli_free_result` functions available. Since you are using `mysql` and `mysql` extension does not have such functions, you can try closing the connection after executing the first procedure and establishing the connection again to execute next procedure. Though this is not the perfect solution, but it will work in your case.

```
mysql_close($connection);
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

You can also try

```
    mysql_free_result($allProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures always return an extra result set with errors/warnings information. As such, your stored procedures return **multiple** result sets (the actual result set from your select query and the extra errors/warnings result set). Calling `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop you only saturate one of them, leaving the other still pending, causing the error you see.

I don't know how to fix it with vanilla `mysql_` library, with `mysqli_` you can issue `mysqli_multi_query`, and then only use the first result set. See the example [in the docs](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fix per se, but if you insist on staying with mysql_* functions, and assuming that you actually want to work with more complicated stored procedures (i.e. that the ones you supplied are just a simplified example) - you can change the stored procedures code to write the resultset into a temporary table (e.g. *tmp_getAllProducts*) instead of returning it, and then *SELECT* from it in your PHP.

This is what worked for me a while back when I was stuck with mysql_* and couldn't upgrade...

Comment: You mean that is a real problem with older mysql

Comment: @Tapas I have had issues with it, yes. I don't remember if it manifested exactly like your issue but I wasn't able to get the `mysql_` functions to get results from stored procedures. It was easy to look up that patch in the code by doing a search for some common curse words found in the surrounding comments...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the mysql extension.  You must either not use more than one stored procedure per connection or upgrade to mysqli.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39727